# Avoiding packet type check by using listening over multiple UDP sockets

Tags: sockets, go, udp, protocol-buffers, marshalling

### Intro

I have a basic server/client UDP setup. I want to be able to optimize marshalling each packet on both endpoints by avoid sending the packet's type within the payload (byte size optimization), and the extra check to determine which type of packet it is, so it knows which type to unmarshal for (compute optimization).

The marshalling of these packets (or messages) are done using Protocol Buffers.

### Known solutions

The accepted answer for this question proposes three solutions, one of which I'm using at the moment:

[Protocol buffers detect type from raw message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121612/protocol-buffers-detect-type-from-raw-message)

However packets will be streaming the network at a high frequency and I feel the extra checks and payload will turn out costly.

To elaborate on why the packet size optimization might be worth while, here is message defined in my .proto file.

```
message Packet {
    OpCode opCode = 1;
    google.protobuf.Any data = 2;
}
```

So the `OpCode` is the variable that defines the packet type and the `Any` is a generic object that could be anything. So when I unmarshall such a packet, I'm essentially doing it twice. Once for the base message, and again for the `Any` based on the `OpCode`. This also means I need to always determine the buffer size of the entire packet. If I can avoid the nested generic object and just send straight as known types, it might reduce the packet size considerably (depending on what protobuf actually does behind the scenes).

### Proposed solution

My initial thought strung from the following:

> For UDP, the socket API allows one socket to receive from many endpoints, and to send to many endpoints - so many servers use just one socket since there isn't any need for more. > [Why a single socket in UDP servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165699/why-a-single-socket-in-udp-servers)

This got me thinking that I can let the server open up multiple UDP sockets, one for each type of packet that will traverse the network, but still be able to communication to many clients.

This allows each socket to always know which packet type to unmarshal for, and have a fixed buffer size to populate (avoid having to check for the length of the packet).

### Known limitations / Assumptions

From what I understand, the OS does put a limit on how many sockets can be opened. However I doubt this will affect me because I will only need max 18 since that is how many packet types I'm aiming for.

### Question

So on a lower network level, since multiple UDP sockets will be open, how will these open sockets be handled? Will each socket handle incoming/outgoing packets concurrently, giving me an additional optimization? Or is it just going to bottleneck when I send a packet to 18000 endpoints because it's all still this "single UDP entity", potentially making my attempt to optimize, not as optimal at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each socket is independent from the others, i.e. has its own send and receiver buffer and the OS kernel might handle these sockets in parallel. This also means that the messages might not be processed in the same order as they were send or received, but this might not be a problem in your case (with UDP you already need to be aware that packet loss, duplicates and reordering might happen). Each of the sockets also needs to bind to a different `<ip,port>` tuple (usually only the port is different) which might make it more complex in case you need to deal with firewalls between sender and receiver.

In general I'm not sure if this optimization is really worth it. With 18 types you need at most 1 byte to encode the type at the beginning of the payload which is marginal compared to the rest of the protocol overhead: The encapsulation into ethernet, IP, UDP already [adds up to 54 bytes with IPv4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4218766/3081018) and then you also have the payload.

Comment: there is also some waste in mapping a socket to a type. All message types are not produced at same frequency. some sockets will be mostly unused and some others will be a lot more used.

Comment: @mh-cbon: compared to using a single UDP socket for all messages this should not be a problem. Compared to using multiple sockets for all types for better scaling this might be a problem though.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I noticed you say "the OS kernel might handle these sockets in parallel". Could you elaborate on that so I can investigate how much of a limitation this could potentially be? 

You raise a good point whether the optimization is worth it, I'll take it into consideration and share what I've found after a benchmarking.

Comment: @FanusduToit: since these are independent sockets with independent send and receive buffers the kernel can read from these buffers or fill these buffers in parallel (assuming a multi-core CPU which is common today). This is also the case if you have different sockets for different clients (i.e. differ by client and not by type) or some other ways of using multiple sockets.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich That makes complete sense, thanks. I've also updated my question a bit to explain how the packet size might be a worthy optimization.

Comment: @FanusduToit: my idea was not to create a new message which includes the type and which has additional marshaling but just add a single byte for the type before each marshaled `data` without further marshaling.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich oh right, ye I get it. I don't think that is possible with protobuf though. I'll have to investigate and perhaps use a different library to do serialization.